# On-Premise Django deployment

Tags: python, deployment, django

I am developing a Django project that's will be hosted on a client private server (On-Premise mode).

I'm new to that because usualy i am deploying my application as SaaS mode, so the client only have the access to the application to use it. that is hosted on my servers or some cloud vendor's servers (Amazon, openshift).

I am searching for the possibility to protect acess to code (python/django), and if so a good configuration to do that on the client's private server.

**EDIT**
Here i mean protection against theft, reversing or snooping the product code.

Comment: Who are you trying to protect the code from?

Comment: The client how will host and use my code, because i'm buying the product not the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protecting Python code from IP theft or other snooping is next to impossible. I have researched this extensively for a product we build at my day job.

If you need to protect this code, you'll either need to host it off site or port it to a compiled language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, here you mean that i have to use another language for developing my application like java ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same issue as the Javascript, HTML and CSS. For these languages the issue is more complicated because even in SaaS deployment model, the code is downloaded on the client side and then executed. Thus, the need is to protect the code (or the IP) to be stolen, not only from your customer, but from the whole world...

The solution taken by Internet giants (google, facebook, twitter, etc..) was to minify and obfuscate their code before deployment...

So, by googling 'python minify' there are some topics and libraries that may fit with your need: https://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/ or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Opy

You may also look about 'python code signature'

I know that this is not a complete answer, but the goal is to give you some ideas on the topic.

Regards